# Is it possible to run a Jenkins job on a slave, use an excel file created as output from the first job and run the next job on Master?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a Jenkins job on a slave. An excel file is created as a result of this first job. 
I want to run a second parametrized job on the master after the first job is completed depending on the value from the excel.

I have tried the following options till now:
 1. **Using the Join Plugin**. This doesn't work because the second job is parametrized and I have to take an input from the excel file. there is no option to provide options or read the parameter from a file.
 2. **Pipeline on master**- For some reason when I create a pipeline on the master and execute the first slave job, the slave job waits for a slot to run since one job is already running and the main job is waiting for the job on the slave to run. So it results in a deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline (scripted, not declarative) sounds like the way to go.

Something like:

```
node('MySlaveLabel') {
  ...do your stuff here...
  stash includes: 'myExcelFile.xls', name: 'myExcelFile'
}

node('MyMasterLabel') {
  unstash 'myExcelFile'
  ...examine your Excel file here..
  ...add conditional statements...
}
```

As long as the node blocks are not nested, you will need only 1 executor on the slave and 1 on the master.

If for some reason you actually need the jobs to call each other:

1. Use the `build 'anotherProject'` syntax.
2. Make sure you have enough executors on the slave.

Comment: That helped. Thanks. I increased the number of executors on the slave and I was able to run the job on it. Also, I was able to code the whole thing using Pipeline. I +1'd the answer but because I am new on Stackoverflow, the response isn't showing.